# Error: Invalid type for parameter, json, in aws cli command

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, aws-cli, ecs-taskdefinition

I am creating a task-definition using `aws` cli that I am running in a Windows `batch-file`, and have to input both `containerPort` and `Hostport`:

```
set name=task_definition_1
set ecs_role_arn=arn:aws:iam::913879294690:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole
set container_name=container_1
set container_uri=913879294690.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sample-containers:resume_ranking

aws ecs register-task-definition --family %name% --task-role-arn %ecs_role_arn% --execution-role-arn %ecs_role_arn% --container-definitions name=%container_name%,image=%container_uri%,memory=128,portMappings={containerPort=7000,hostPort=7000}
```

At the end of the last line of code, I am trying to input:

```
portMappings={containerPort=7000,hostPort=7000}
```

This is the output I receive:

```
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].portMappings[0].containerPort, value: 7000, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'int'>
Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].portMappings[0].hostPort, value: 7000, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'int'>
```

How can I input this json in the correct format?

Comment: Input this `json`? There is no `json` here, you are inputting via `cli`

Comment: I have read different solutions around, perhaps some of them wrong, how should I input both 7000 for containerPort and hostPort?